# Matplotlib contour distortion with large x-values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graphics, contour

Can anyone offer any information why this contour-graph gets distorted when the x-values are large? At least in my mind the figure should stay exactly the same, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding something.

The figure when using shift = 0 (or up to shift = 100000):

[image]

The figure when using shift = 1000000:

[image]

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as ml

shift = 0 # works
# shift = 1000000 # distorts the graph because of ?

x = np.array([7, 3, 3, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 2, 7]) + shift
y = np.array([1, 8, 1, 5, 6, 5, 8, 4, 1, 8])
z = np.array([0.5485118, 0.53838622, 0.93582844, 0.13831005, 0.45559201,
              0.4032324, 0.73419538, 0.03208198, 0.55323105, 0.95654892])

xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 200)
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 200)
zi = ml.griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')

plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, 15, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
plt.pcolormesh(xi, yi, zi, cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow'))

plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', c='b', s=5, zorder=10)
plt.show()
```

I'm using matplotlib==1.4.3, numpy==1.9.2, python==2.7.11

In case you're wondering, this code is just a demonstration of the problem. I noticed this odd behaviour when trying to plot a contour with x-axis consisting of timedeltas (in seconds) to Unix UTC epoch, and I'm now trying to figure out the right way to deal with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably running into float rounding issues because the x and y are on very different scales.  Can you report this as an issue to mpl?

Comment: Ok, gotta try to work around this problem then in some way. As in: not use timedeltas in the code. I'll also try to report this soon and see what the people of MPL think about it. Thanks!